# Python Pandas Pivot - Why Fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have tried for a while to get this to wrk and I can't - I read the documentation and I must be misunderstanding something

I have a Data Frame in long format and I want to make it wide - this is quite common. But I get an error

```
from pandas import DataFrame 
data = DataFrame({'value' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                  'group' : ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','d']})
data.pivot(columns='group')
```

the error I get is (the lats part, as they are quite extensive): ValueError: cannot label index with a null key

I tried this in python (notebook) and also on regular python c command line in OS X with the same result

Thanks for any insight, I am sure it will be something basic

Comment: Are you sure you need pivot? what about `data.T`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what you were trying to do, you were trying to pass 'group' as `index` so the pivot fails.
It should be:

```
data.pivot(data.index, 'group')
```

or,

```
# the format is pivot(index=None, columns=None, values=None)
data.pivot(index=data.index, columns='group')
```

However I'm not entirely sure what expected output you want, if you just want shorter presentation, you can always use `transpose`:

```
data.T
```

or, the best for presentation in your case, is `groupby`:

```
data.groupby('group').sum()
       value
group       
a          6
b         22
c         27
d         23
```

Comment: thanks. This works. I was trying to have one column for all the a values, one for all the b, etc. and I realize that since they are not equally long I will get NAs, in real life I would use it for equal sets